# Stackoverflow Login is not working on FF 15

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, login, firefox

When I click Login from OPENID on FireFox 15. It shows me that you are logged in. Refresh the Browser. When I do this. I am still not Logged-in. Any one has this same issue?

I am asking this question on Chrome.

Update: Here is the screen cast, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pt2-vE0DfHA

Update: It Starts working now. Now there is popup for refresh which I was seeing from couple of years.

Comment: Works for me. Which OpenID provider are you using?

Comment: It *tells* you to refresh the browser? In a "Welcome back" notification in the top bar? But then you did NOT enter any OpenID details to get logged in, right? Please be more precise while describing the behaviour you see.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I am using myopenid?

Comment: @Arjan, I just refresh the browser. It will will redirect me to Main Page without as a logged-in user.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, here is the screencast, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pt2-vE0DfHA

Comment: Any solutions??